# Error with my Javascript code

Tags: javascript

You have an array of numbers. Write a function that will transform the array to an array of functions that return the original numbers, so instead of calling a[3], we will call a3. For example:

transform([1,2,3]) → [function () {return 1;}, function () {return 2;}, function () {return 3;}] 
Please don't use 'eval' or 'new Function' in your answer as we consider these bad style.

I cant run this, some error that I cant find out

```
var arrayOfNum = [0,1,2];

var arraylength = arrayOfNum.length;

for(var i = 0; i < arraylength; i++){
var hold = arrayOfNum.pop();
function passValue(num){
arrayOfNum.unshift(function(){return hold;});
}
}
```

can anyone help me to point out the mistake in this code

Comment: what error are you getting, sir?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the `passValue` function, so after the `pop` line, nothing is actually being executed. I don't think the function can even be called, since its scope inside the `for` loop should prevent it being bound to the enclosing function. Apart from attempting to redefine the function 3 times...

```
var arrayOfNum = [0,1,2];
var arraylength = arrayOfNum.length;

for(var i = 0; i < arraylength; i++){
    var hold = arrayOfNum.pop();
    function passValue(num){
        arrayOfNum.unshift( function(){return hold;} );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rahul: That depends on what you want the code to do. What is the passValue function for?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox you can see javascript errors in the error console (Tools -> Error Console).

You don't seem to have an error at all, but nothing just happens i guess. What are you trying to do anyway? I see a function passValue() inside the forloop that's never called.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not obvious what you want to do. I may guess that you want to replace the numbers by functions, if so you may write:

```
var arrayOfNum = [0,1,2];

var arraylength = arrayOfNum.length;

for(var i = 0; i < arraylength; i++){
    var hold = arrayOfNum.pop();
    function passValue(num){
        arrayOfNum.unshift(function(){return num;});
    }
    passValue(hold);
}

alert(arrayOfNum[0]()); //0
alert(arrayOfNum[1]()); //1
alert(arrayOfNum[2]()); //2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *map* you can achieve desired result + very short and clean code:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr = arr.map(function(n) {
    return function() { return n; }
});
```